# APK fails to install the second time

Tags: android, apk

I generate APK by doing following in Android Studio:
Build -> Build APK(s).

I copy this APK in Phone's memory and launch it. It installs fine, but only for the first time. I then uninstall existing app and launch the same APK again, now it says "App Not Installed".

If I copy the same APK from my computer to this phone again, then again it installs for the first time only.

Comment: What do you mean "launch the same APK again"? What steps do you take to do this?

Comment: Try reproducing the process while opening logCat and look for any error message related to the installation of the APK. This may be helpful because without any error report, finding the solution will be impossible

Comment: Try with release apk.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I mean, I launch the APK from the phone's memory using some File explorer app, first time it installs fine. Then I uninstall the app and then launch the same APK that I launched first time and it fails.

Comment: @ArthurAttout I just tried it. Surprisingly the issue is not occurring any more. I am installing the same APK again n again (after uninstalling app every time) and it is installing fine :/ . I am trying this after 2 days and from a different city. It is working fine now. In the 2 days time, my phone also was restarted. May be something has fixed it. The problem was occurring on my friend's phone as well, so it is not just my phone.. Not sure what the issue was.

Comment: @M.UsmanKhan, I have same issue. Can you solve it?

Comment: @DevOma It got resolved automatically next day.. So i guess u'll have to wait.

Comment: It seems to happen only to apps that haven't been submitted to the store before (so the package name is not know by google)

Answer (score 37):

Problem with Google play update, Open playstore -> Play protect and turning off Scanning device for security threats.

Comment: Thanks. But now I cant validate the solutions as I am not being able to reproduce the problem anymore.

Comment: correct, this worked in my situation: trying to reinstall an app that has never been submitted to Google Play before. ( we are still in development and distributing via App Center)

Comment: Thanks! Still don't get, why this only happens while the app is installed the second time.

Comment: Yes that is awesome, Thanks very helpful for me as well. Can we do something in our code so that we do not need to take care about that option?

Answer (score 0):

To run your app on a device, you should plug the device into your development computer with a USB cable. In Android Studio, select the `app` Run Configuration and click on the Run button. You shouldn't copy the APK directly to the phone. Let Android Studio install it instead. For more details, read [Run your app](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app) from the official Android documentation.

Comment: That's an alternative, sure, but it doesn't explain why the situation of the question does not work, when it should.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The situation of the question is unclear because it doesn't give step-by-step details that lead to the problem.

Comment: My client is lives abroad. So i need to send him APK to test on his device.

Comment: @M.UsmanKhan Don't have your client uninstall the app. Just increase the `versionCode` by 1 and set an appropriate `versionName` and have them install the upgrade.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice right. This may work as well, though the issue above shouldn't have occurred anyway.

Comment: Please suggest the solution for this. Facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Please Disable **Instant Run**

> (File >Settings >Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run)

**2)** Trying cleaning AND rebuilding your project

**3)** Make sure that your phone is properly connected to your PC with a USB cable and try to install the app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I uninstalled my debug apk from my device. For my case, I solved the problem by "Build" -> "Clear Project"  then  "Rebuild Project". Then I can install the newly rebuilt apk.